# How to add meta data in a csv using python?

Tags: python, django, csv, metadata, export-to-csv

I am trying to create a csv file to export user list.
I want to add some meta data like the type of user, author and some other data that should not be displayed in excel sheet. 
Is it possible to add such meta datas in CSV. if possible can some one help me?

Comment: That isn't possible in a .csv. It is a very simple file structure of rows and columns. Any metadata would have to go into a separate accompanying file.

Comment: I was not aware about it. Thank you @BoarGules

Comment: Better is to add 1 more column which will refer the corresponding meta data rows in other CSV. Here you have to store all meta data in other CSV.  It is like inner joining 2 csvs while getting values from both.

Answer (score 0):

As the guy in the comment mentioned.  You can't use CSV to save metadata. It is a file format that holds its data in a comma separated way. Nothing more than that.

However, If your only usage is in microsoft excel, you can use XlsxWriter to create excel file and [change document properties](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/workbook.html#workbook-set-properties).